# weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.rmi.ConnectException: Destination 141.1.251.4, 7096 unreachable; nested exception is:

Tags: java, weblogic

We are getting below exception during staring of the one of the managed server in weblogic 12c.

We have done some migration changes:

1. code changes from ejb2 to ejb3
2. weblogic11g to weblogic12c.

When we start one of the managerserver (all other servers down) getting below exception, can any one help me?

```
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; No available router to destination
 weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.rmi.ConnectException: Destination 141.1.251.2, 7096 unreachable; nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; No available router to destination
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:114)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:175)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:170)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:80)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.rmi.ConnectException: Destination 141.1.251.2, 7096, 7096 unreachable; nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; No available router to destination
    at weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.bootstrap(ConnectionManager.java:490)
    at weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.bootstrap(ConnectionManager.java:328)
    at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMManager.findOrCreateRemoteInternal(RJVMManager.java:309)
    at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMManager.findOrCreate(RJVMManager.java:213)
    at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreateRemoteServer(RJVMFinder.java:263)
```

Comment: 'No available route' is pretty clear. Can you ping that IP address from that server? And is that the IP address you expected to see?

Comment: But if I deploy ejb2 code in the weblogic12c not getting that kind of exception.